# Bash - Need to get records with line numbers if found duplicates based on first two column values

Tags: bash

Need to help in Bash to print duplicate records in a file with the corresponding line number.
Duplicates are to be identified based on first two column combination.

Example:

```
111|abc|scientist
222|ghu|developer
222|thu|doctor
222|ghu|engineer
```

I need output as below as duplicate is based on combination of 1st 2 columns along with its line number:

```
2, 222|ghu|developer
4, 222|ghu|engineer
```

Comment: Welcome! What have been your attempts to solve it? Awk will be the tool of choice here.

Comment: When you post what you have coded up to now, I will post my solution.

Comment: I should have waited before posting my solution that you showed what you tried, but since I have to leave, I will post it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input is in file input.txt, try:

```
awk -F '|' '{if (t[$1$2]) {print t[$1$2]; print NR", "$0} t[$1$2] = NR", "$0}' input.txt
```

Improving the readability:

```
awk -F '|' '{
  if (t[$1$2]) {
    print t[$1$2]
    print NR", "$0
  } 
  t[$1$2] = NR", "$0
}' input.txt
```